# Addclass for period of time on Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a following HTML

```
<div id="btn_1">Button 1</div>
<div id="btn_2">Button 1</div>
<div id="btn_3">Button 1</div>
```

I want add a css class for period of time, for example: If the hour is between 00:00 to 06:59  add class "select" to id "btn_1", for between 07:00 to 10:59 am add the class to id "btn_2", and finally 11:00 to 16:00 add class to id "btn_3".

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    // get hour of time
    var hour = (new Date).getHours();

    // remove select class if already applied
    $('.select').removeClass('select');

    if (hour < 7) {  // 0:00 to 6:59
        $('#btn_1').addClass('select');
    } else if (hour < 11) {  // 7:00 to 10:59
        $('#btn_2').addClass('select');
    } else if (hour < 16) {  // 11:00 to 15:59
        $('#btn_3').addClass('select');
    }

})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fS3jj/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```
var classes = ['select', 'btn_1', 'btn_2', 'btn_3');

$('div')
// Remove any of the existing defined classes added to elements.
.removeClass(classes.join(' '))
// Add the class based on the hour of the day.
.addClass(function() {
    var hour = (new Date).getHours();

    if (hour < 6) {
        return classes[0];
    } else if (hour < 10) {
        return classes[1];
    } else if (hour < 15) {
        return classes[2];
    }

    return classes[3];
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MyTmU/).

Alternatively, you could use an object to hold the `classes` where each value is the upper hour bound, and pass `Object.keys(classes).join(' ')` to `removeClass()`.

Then you could greatly, simplify the body of the `addClass()` function.

However, I didn't go with this solution because `Object.keys()` does not have the best browser support and shimming it inline with a `for ( in )` is verbose.